# Web apps integration with event based services

Tags: web, events, queue, microservices

I am looking for a best practise when connecting a web application (a React single page app for example) with pure event based backend (microservices, ActiveMQ for example).

When I do a GET call from React (which is request response), how do I get the response considering all backend services are event based?

My thoughts are:

1. Execute the GET command
2. Have a REST controller service in the backend (request-response) which fires an event and returns back a response that everything went ok
3. On the client side, the signal is caught, but nothing happens, just keep loading
4. Event is processed meanwhile in the backend, which fires another "response" event when done, to which (using stickiness or similar approach) the same REST controller listens
5. The controller sends the actual response to the browser, using websockets (or similar)
6. Browser gets the response, display the results

I know there are workarounds, but I am looking for the best event-based solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Execute the GET command

That's right

> Have a REST controller service in the backend (request-response) which
>   fires an event and returns back a response that everything went ok

Yes and you would return a reference ID that client can use to track the progress.

> On the client side, the signal is caught, but nothing happens, just
>   keep loading

Depends. If you want client to wait then you keep on show loading. If it's a long process then you may not block the user and send the notification later that it's done.

> Event is processed meanwhile in the backend, which fires another
>   "response" event when done, to which (using stickiness or similar
>   approach) the same REST controller listens

In decoupled architecture every thing is async. Means fire and forget. When you return reference id to client, the controller is done you can't block anything. Client would use that id to check the progress (cache / DB etc). If you are going websocket path then possible controller could notify based on status change.

you already have the understanding , so it really depends on the workflow you are trying to build.

Answer (score 1):

You could go this route:

1. Backend "processor" subscribes to a job queue
2. Execute the GET command
3. REST controller subscribes to a new queue using client id. Publishes event (which contains client id) to processor's job queue. Returns OK to client.
4. Backend "processor" completes job and publishes completed event to the queue designated by the client id.
5. REST controller receives completed event and deletes the queue (no longer needed). Returns response to client using websocket.